# Measure theory application of dominated convergence theorem

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification, lebesgue-measure

I am trying to get practice evaluating integrals with measure theory. I found the following problem online from some old lecture notes and am trying to solve it:

Problem:
Let $(X, A, \mu)$ be a measure space and $f_{i}: (X, A) \rightarrow (\mathbb(R), B(\mathbb{R}))$ be a non-negative function for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$. Suppose that $f_{i}(x) \geq f_{i+1}(x)$ for all $i \in \mathbb{N}, x \in X$ and let $f(x) = \lim_{i \to \infty}f_{i}(x)$ for all $x \in X$.

1. Prove that $f$ is a well-defined function and $\int_{X} f_{1}d\mu < \infty \Rightarrow \lim_{i \to \infty} \int_{X}f_{i}d\mu = \int_{X}f d\mu$.
2. Do there exist a sequence of functions with the above criterion and $\int_{X}f_{i}d\mu = \infty$ for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$ but $\lim_{i \to \infty}\int_{X}f_{i}d \mu \neq \int_{X}f d\mu$

Attempt:

1. **I am not sure what I need to do to show the function is well defined.** Do I take $x=y$ and show $\lim_{i \to \infty} f_{i}(x) = \lim_{i \to \infty} f_{i}(y)?$. The $f_{i}(x)$ converges pointwise to $f(x)$. Letting $g(x) = f_{1}(x)$ then for all $i \in \mathbb{N}, |f_{i}(x)| \leq g(x)$, hence we can apply Dominated Convergence Theorem:

Hence $ \lim_{i \to \infty} \int_{X}|f_{i}(x) - f(x)|d \mu = 0$. **How do I then get the equality?**

2. Yes there do exist such functions. Consider $f_{i}(x) = i\chi_{(0, \frac{1}{i}]}(x)$. Then $f_{i}(x)$ converges pointwise to $0$. However we cannot satisfy the condition $|f_{i}(x)| \leq g(x)$. We have $\int_{X}\lim_{i \to \infty}f_{i}d\mu = 0$ but $\lim_{i \to \infty}\int_{X}f_{i}(x)d\mu = 1 $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding question 1), it is not 100% clear but I think you are asked to show that $f : x\mapsto \lim\limits_{i\to\infty} f_i(x)$ is measurable, since the function is already well defined (we have to assume the pointwise limit exists otherwise the question makes no sense).

If so, a common way to prove it is to show that $\limsup\limits_{i\to\infty} f_i$ and $\liminf\limits_{i\to\infty} f_i$ are both measurable, which is enough to conclude by the definition of the limit (**hint :** write the events $\{x: \limsup\limits_{i\to\infty} f_i(x) \le t\}$ as countable unions and intersections of events involving the $f_i$).

After that you can apply DCT, and you conclude that the integrals are equal since, by triangle inequality :
$$0\le \left\lvert\int_{X}f_{i}(x)d \mu - \int_X f(x)d \mu\right\rvert\le \int_{X}|f_{i}(x) - f(x)|\ d \mu $$

For question 2), I think your counterexample is not correct, because you have to ensure that the domination condition $f_{i}(x) \geq f_{i+1}(x)$ still holds true for all $x$ and that the integrals $\int_X f_i$ are NOT finite. Instead, for $(X,A) = (\mathbb R,\mathscr B(\mathbb R))$, you can consider the sequence of constant maps $f_i : x\mapsto \frac 1 i$. You can check that in this case the domination condition still holds but $\lim_{i \to \infty}\int_{\mathbb R}f_{i}(x)d\mu = \infty$ and $\int_{\mathbb R}\lim_{i \to \infty}f_{i}(x)d\mu = 0$.

Comment: Thanks this makes sense and good catch on the domination condition holding. I know this follows from Dominated Convergence, but if we have $\int_{X}|f_{i}(x) - f(x)|d\mu = 0$ how do we then get $\int_{X}\lim_{i \to \infty}f_{i} = \lim_{i \to \infty}\int_{X}f_{i}$?

Comment: This is just the triangle inequality + DCT, as you noticed, we have
$$0\le \lim_{i\to\infty}\left\lvert\int_{X}f_{i}(x)d \mu - \int_X f(x)d \mu\right\rvert\le \lim_{i\to\infty}\int_{X}|f_{i}(x) - f(x)|\ d \mu = 0 $$
Hence
$$ \lim_{i\to\infty}\int_{X}f_{i}(x)d \mu - \int_X f(x)d \mu = 0$$
So
$$ \lim_{i \to \infty}\int_{X}f_{i}(x) = \int_X f(x)d \mu =  \int_X \lim_{i\to\infty} f_i(x) $$
(by definition of $f$)